# Cookie в DB/File

Tags: php, cookie, mysql

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как записать куки в БД MySQL или же в файл..
Что-то типо этого:

```
$random =  rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
setcookie ("xuid", $random, 999999999999)
```

Записать в БД/Файл

Answer (score 2):

1. Не самый лучший вариант для uid использовать *rand(1000000000, 9999999999)*, лучше [session_id](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php) или например md5(time() + salt);
2. Записать в БД/Файл - этот пункт загадочен. Может [это (подключение к БД)](http://www.komtet.ru/lib/plangs/php/podklyuchenie-k-bd-skript-php) или [это (работа с файлами)](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=fs&page=005) (как вариант [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php)) вам поможет?